# detect mouse clicks in OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, glut

I am a beginner at OpenGL and I am trying to create a game in which as background I have a raw image. When the game starts I display that image and I want to be able to click on it and to display another image afterwards. I tried using the function `glutMouseFunc` but when I try to run the program I receive a message which says that the program stopped working. 
Here are some parts of my code: I have a global variable onMouse; if I click the mouse button the variable takes the value 1 and if it has the value 1 I try to load the second image.

```
int onMouse;
void mouseClicks(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        onMouse = 1;
    }
}
```

And this is the main function:

```
//load first texture
texture = LoadTextureRAW( "2 Lock screen.raw", TRUE );
glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
if(onMouse == 1){
    //load second texture
    texture = LoadTextureRAW( "in_game.raw", TRUE );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** I have made some changes to the code, but the background image still doesn't change. Here is the new main function:

```
glutCreateWindow("Game");
texture = LoadTextureRAW( "2 Lock screen.raw", 1 );
glutDisplayFunc(display);

glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
glutKeyboardFunc(key);

glutMainLoop();

if(onMouse == 1){
        texture = LoadTextureRAW( "in_game.raw", 2 );
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
}
```

And this is the display function in which I map the texture to a quad:

```
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

// setup texture mapping
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

glPushMatrix();
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex3d(1.0,1.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex3d(-1.0,1.0,1.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex3d(-1.0,-1.0, -1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex3d(1.0,-1.0, 1.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();

// free the texture
FreeTexture( texture );
```

Comment: Your question is about GLUT, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the order wrong.

```
glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
```

Here you register the function to be called when the mouse is clicked.

```
if(onMouse == 1) {
```

You immediately check if the mouse had been clicked. It's impossible for the mouse to have been clicked in the brief period between these two lines, and `glutMainLoop` hasn't been entered yet so your program didn't even have a chance to listen for mouse events.

---

As for the crash, I can't help you debug it with just the code you have provided. Please try a debugger and find which line causes the crash.

Comment: I changed the order and now I have glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks) between the functions DisplayFunc() and KeyboardFunc() and after the call of glutMainLoop() I check to see if onMouse has the value 1; the program still doesn't change the image but at least now I doesn't crash

Answer (score 6):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're expecting glutMouseFunc to wait for a mouse click. This is not how GLUT works (GLUT is not part of OpenGL BTW). Another callback to be registered is the drawing function (usually called `display` in GLUT based programs).

Once you enter the GLUT main loop (`glutMainLoop()` call) user events are processed and if a redisplay is requested the display function is called.

So here's what you do (in simplified pseudocode)

```
// Define bitmasks for mouse status, we assume mice have less than 17 buttons
#define MB_LEFT   0
#define MB_MIDDLE 1
#define MB_RIGHT  2
#define LMB_PRESSED (1<<0)
#define MMB_PRESSED (1<<1)
#define RMB_PRESSED (1<<2)
#define LMB_CLICKED (1<<16)
#define MMB_CLICKED (1<<17)
#define RMB_CLICKED (1<<18)
#define MB_PRESSED(state, button) (1<<(button))
#define MB_CLICKED(state, button) (1<<((button)+16)))
#define MB_MASK_PRESSED 0x0000ffffL
#define MB_MASK_CLICKED 0xffff0000L

uint32_t mouse_status = 0;

void onMouseButton(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    int b;
    switch(button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:   b=MB_LEFT;   break;
    case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON: b=MB_MIDDLE; break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:  b=MB_RIGHT;  break;
    }

    if(mouse_status & MB_PRESSED(b) && GLUT_UP == state) {
        mouse_status |= MB_CLICKED(b);
    }
    if( !(mouse_status & MB_PRESSED(b)) && GLUT_DOWN == state) {
        mouse_status = (mouse_status & ~(0L | MB_CLICKED(b))) | MB_PRESSED(b);
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
    if(mouse_status & MB_CLICKED(MB_LEFT)) {
        /* do something */
        …

        /* clear the click flag */
        mouse_status &= ~MB_MASK_CLICKED;
    }
}

int main(…)
{
    …
    glutCreateWindow(…);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(onMouseButton);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

You can of course use any other kind of structure you like to pass the mouse button status between program parts. I prefer bitmasks for such. Other people may prefer arrays (personally I don't like arrays for tasks like this, because they're not as easy to look at in a debugger than a simple bitfield).

Answer (score 1):

`glutMouseFunc` registers a callback: a function to be called on specific events (here mouse events). These events are collected by `glutMainLoop`, which has not been called yet when you test `onMouse`.

Another thing, though I cannot tell for sure from the small code excerpt you provide, is that you'd better load the assets from the start of the programme, rather than wait for a user event to do it. Load them first, and simply change `texture` to whichever id correspond to the texture you wish to display then.